# Populating a string array with ints

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have a **string array** that I want to populate with integers from **1000 - 9999**. How do I populate it properly? I searched around for this question and seemed to have found it but I am still getting an error from eclipse. Here is my code

```
 String[] eliminated = new String[9000];

 for(int j = 1000; j <= 9999 ; j++){
        eliminated.add(Integer.toString(j));
    }
```

I keep getting an error inside the curly braces of my for loop. Can someone explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

Note: My project specifically required that I do not use an Arraylist

Comment: `add()` method is only available for `List` interface implementations *(ArrayList, ArrayDeque, HashSet, etc)*. `String` is not a List implementation. Therefore, you have to use `eliminated[j]` to fill your `String` *array*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up ArrayList syntax with array. Assign elements using array syntax ( I have written this code based on java)

```
String[] eliminated = new String[9000];    
for(int j = 0; j < eliminated.length; j++){
        eliminated[j] = Integer.toString(j+1000);
    }
```

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @ephemient Thanks, Fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

method `add(String)` cannot be used with array. Use `Arraylist` instead.